# BQ Query - add whitespace after comma

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, whitespace

I am writing a query in BQ and it is returning a concatenated comma separated String with no whitespace. I want to add a whitespace after the comma.

All the things I have tried that work in other SQL queries as in CONCAT_WS, etc. are not working.

Query:

````
   CASE WHEN u2.reportsDown IS NULL THEN u1.reportsUp ELSE CONCAT(u1.reportsUp, ", ",   u2.reportsDown) END as accountLIST
   FROM ```

Result:
```12345,67890,09876,54321,102938,564738```

Desired Result:
```12345, 67890, 09876, 54321, 102938, 564738```

Even adding a _ after the comma is not doing anything. Not even the _ is showing up.

Does anyone know how I can get a whitespace after the comma in a BQ query?

Thank you!
````

Comment: i cannot reproduce your case  - please provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I cannot. The data being returned is from various datasets in a project. The code I posted is a line from that query that has a ", " in it

Answer (score 0):

Was able to use the REPLACE function in BQ to add the whitespace

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).